# htaccess redirect without directory

Tags: .htaccess

I want to make a redirect (using .htaccess) to an external site that host where my app can be downloaded so I can give users  a url to `server.com/install` but when I add

`Redirect 301 / http://google.com/` to my install directory it redirects to `http://google.com/install` which is not what I want.

How can I accomplish this with htaccess?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You say you want to direct users to `server.com/install`, but your redirect goes to google.com? Try putting all of the steps in your question. 1) the URL the user first goes to. 2) where you want them to be directed to. 3) Any additional steps.

Comment: Also include the .htaccess code that you've tried.

Comment: That's all I have in my .htaccess file. `Redirect 301 / http://google.com/` I basically want to be able to tell a user to go to server.com/install so they can install my app. It will redirect them to a long url with that version. When I test it, it goes to otherurl.com/install rather than otherurl.com/ which I put in the htaccess..

Comment: You're saying that your .htaccess file contains a redirect to `http://google.com` and that is causing users to arrive at `otherurl.com/install`? That's real magic going on, sorry, but I can't help with that.

Comment: no, it's going to google.com/install instead of google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` automatically appends anything from the original URL to the new URL.

Give this a try:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/ http://google.com [L,R=301]
```

---

One more attempt, I added the RewriteBase and wildcard to match all. But I think the problem was that there was no trailing `/` after `google.com`. Maybe someone else will answer if this doesn't work.

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://google.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It is still redirecting to google.com/install do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I forgot the "^" carrot before the slash. I edited it to `^/`

Comment: I tried clearing the cache and using your approach but I received an 403 Forbidden Error